# iOS device version 9.3.2 not connected to xcode 7.3.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Unfortunatly my ipad version is updated to 9.3.2, and it's not connected to my xcode latest version(7.3.1).My mac os x version is EI Captaion(10.11.4).

can anyone please suggest me, how this issue fix.

Comment: what the issue u faced'

Comment: Have you change deployment target from general category of Xcode?

Comment: yes i changed development target to 9.3, but my device ios version is 9.3.2.

Comment: What error message are you getting?  What do you see in the devices window?  What happens when you try and set your iPad as the deployment target?  Have you restarted the iPad?  Have you restarted your Mac?

Comment: Yes Mr.Paulw, i restarted my iPad and my mac several times, still getting same error message like "An error was encountered while enabling development on this device. Please try rebooting and reconnecting the device. (0xE800000E)"

Comment: I think you should have to go with Xcode 8 beta version to make it work

Comment: http://prntscr.com/biklro

Comment: Please make sure you have  xcode/Contents/Developer/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/9.3 and also in plist file in xcode

Comment: @JigarTarsariya Why would trying Xcode 8 beta help?

Comment: This morning, my iPad got updated, so I'm now on the same version of iOS and Xcode as you... and everything runs okay.  BUT - last week I had a similar problem (refused to accept my valid certificate) and to make it go away, I had to reset the iPad  (shut it down completely, then turn it back on again).